# Notification icon in status bar without taking over status bar for several seconds?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I know how to send a notification to the status bar, but when it first starts it takes over the whole status bar and you can't see anything else but your icon. Is there any way to show your icon without it taking over the whole status bar for a few seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using an empty `tickerText`.  Just set that to `null` and the system won't attempt to show it.

Comment: thanks so much. the code i was using was: Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
       "" , System.currentTimeMillis()); and what was wrong was i had it empty message("") and i should have had null there instead. Thanks a lot it fixed it :)

Comment: one more thing how can i get rid of System.currentTimeMillis()) in notification when i take it out or put null there it gives me error?

Comment: @jolee The time is mandatory.  That's what the system uses for the timestamp to show the user, and it's how it sorts the icons and notifications.  It doesn't make sense to set it to `null`.

Comment: yea i got rid of the time in status bar anyway but putting in 0